# Set DefaultValue for Color using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

With the following Test class

```
public class Test {
    [DefaultValue("Black")] 
    public Color ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

And the following serialization code:

```
var test = new Test();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
    new JsonSerializerSettings {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
});
```

I get

```
{"ForeColor":"Black"}
```

Is there a (simple) way to have a Color property not serialized if it's the same as a specified default value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default values stored in the [`DefaultValueAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) are specific to their type. So if you specify a default value of `"Black"`, then the default value is an actual string even though the property type is of a different type.

In order to work with other non-simple types, you have to use [a special overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx59291k.aspx) of the attribute and specify the object type and a string value that can be converted into the target type using a known type converter.

Luckily, the [`Color` struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) does have a type converter registered. So you can use it like this:

```
public class Test
{
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
    public Color ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

And then it works as desired:

```
var test = new Test();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, new JsonSerializerSettings {
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
});
Console.WriteLine(json); // {}
```

Comment: I ran this exact code and got {"ForeColor":"0, 0, 0, 255"} as output, any ideas what could be wrong? edit: Oh, I was using the XNA Color class not System.Drawing.

Comment: @JavidPack Is it working for you now then? Or are you asking how to do that with XNA Color?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I figured it out. The TypeConverter is different for the XNA Color, it only accepts a string of 4 comma separated numbers: This is what I ended up with: [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "165,42,42,255")]